# Two fields being focused at the same time

Tags: java, blackberry, user-interface

I'm developing a blackberry application and I'm having some problems setting the initial field focused (which isn't the fist field in the manager). This is a piece of code of the screen's constructor:

```
public class BaseScreen extends MainScreen {

    ...
    public BaseScreen() {

        ...
        //adding fields to attribute _body(Manager) including the field to be focused
        ...

        add(_body)
        _body.setFieldWithFocus(fieldToFocus);

    }
    ...
}
```

As it turns out, the field **`fieldToFocus`** does paint itself as focused once the screen is shown. But so does the first field of the **`_body`** manager. This means I have two fields focused at the same time!

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Did you implement `onFocus`, `onUnfocus` methods of the `fieldToFocus` and first field? If not then implement those and invoke `invalidate` from them. This will cause a force repaint, and only the field with focus will have the look as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try replacing this:

_body.setFieldWithFocus(fieldToFocus);

with this:

fieldToFocus.setFocus();

I am interested to know if this resolves your problem.

The method you have tried to use (setFieldWithFocus()) is not one that I have used in the past, and the fact that you see two focused Fields is an interesting effect.  Can you tell use what OS and device (Simulator) you are seeing this on.